# why does ld linker work with pointer and array in different ways

Tags: c, assembly, linker, kernel, ld

I have such **asm** code:

```
format ELF

public _start
extrn _kernel_main

section ".text" executable

_start:
    movzx edx, dl
    push edx
    push esi
    push ebx
    call _kernel_main
 @@:
    jmp @b

;section ".data" writable
```

and such ld script:

```
ENTRY(_start)

KERNEL_BASE = 0xFFC00000;

SECTIONS {
    .text KERNEL_BASE : {
        *(.text)
        *(.code)
        *(.rdata*)
    }
    .data ALIGN(0x1000) : {
        *(.data)
    }
    .bss ALIGN(0x1000) : {
        *(.bss)
    }
    .empty ALIGN(0x1000) - 1 : {
        BYTE(0)
    }
}
```

It works fine with this c code:

```
void kernel_main() {
    char *screen_buffer = (void*)0xB8000;
    char msg[] = "Hello, World!";
    unsigned int i = 24 * 80;
    screen_buffer[i * 2] = *msg;
    int j = 0;
    while (msg[j] != '\0') {
        screen_buffer[i * 2] = *(msg + j);
        j++;
        i++;
    }   
}
```

but if I try to use this code:

```
void kernel_main() {
    char *screen_buffer = (void*)0xB8000;
    char *msg = "Hello world!";
    unsigned int i = 24 * 80;
    while (*msg) {
        screen_buffer[i * 2] = *msg;
        msg++;
        i++;
    }
}
```

it stops correct execution and doesn't display any character.

The c code do the same thing.

I don't see any differenct between **char msg[] = "Hello, World!";** and **char *msg = "Hello, World!";**
Could someone please tell me where I'm wrong.

Comment: String constant usually goes into `.rodata` not `.rdata`. Make sure you use proper linker script.

Comment: In the `char msg[]` case the string may even end up being built with stores of constants (i.e. embedded in the instructions immediate), making it work even with a broken linker script.

Comment: Actually `char msg[] = "Hello, World!";` lives on the stack. The compiler may initialize it either directly or with a copy from `.rodata`. In this case it presumably used immediate moves which is why it works.

Comment: `char *msg` is a separate object holding the address of the read-only string literal, which itself has an address in `.rodata`.

`char msg[] = ...` at global scope would put a name (label/symbol) on the string data itself, in `.data`.  There is no pointer stored in memory (except in the metadata, the symbol table.)  But as a local in a function like you're doing, it's just initialized on the stack from immediates or by coping data from an auto-numbered label in `.rodata`.  [**Look at your compiler output:**](//stackoverflow.com/q/38552116).

Comment: `.rdata` would be correct for Windows, but this is ELF so the standard section name is `.rodata`; that's where compilers will put stuff.

Comment: Take a look at the object code the compiler generates in both cases to get another perspective on the answer to your question: what's the difference.  To reiterate what others are saying, the `msg[] = ""` version is an array declaration with an array initializer where the array initializer looks like (takes the syntactic form of) a string literal but isn't actually a string literal (it just identifies the bytes for initializing the array, any way the compiler wants to do it), and the `msg* = ""` version is a pointer declaration with a real string literal's address taken as an initializer.

Comment: Thank you for answers! Btw I checked the obj file and it contains rdata, not rodata.

Comment: You're probably on Windows if you got `.rdata`.  Probably a good idea to use an ELF cross-compiler instead of a compiler that targets native Windows, especially if you want to use FASM `format ELF`, or just in general for kernel development.

Comment: Got it, Peter, thank you! Btw I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I just skiped the **-c** compiler option:

```
gcc src\kernel.c -o bin\main.o -c
```

-c      compile and assemble, but do not link.